# Why use RabiitMQ as broker AND redis as results backend?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery, messagebroker

from celery docs:

> Or if you want to use Redis as the result backend, but still use
>   RabbitMQ as the message broker (a popular combination):

I understand HOW to use RabbitMQ as a message broker and Redis as the results backend...

I don't understand why this is a popular combination and what benefits it brings, everywhere i search for an explanation i find opinions about why one is better than the other, but never an argument for why to use them in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Redis and memcached are OBVIOUS choices whenever you have to deal with keys/values that have expiry date. This is perfect choice for Celery result backend. Not to mention that Redis can be configured to be highly available (cluster or sentinel mode).

Finally, in my humble opinion, *nothing* beats Redis simplicity.